# Floating image right of table.Is it possible?

Tags: css

new to css .

In asp.net mvc 3 I load a list of customers in a table.

Next to this table I would like to float some images.How do you do it in css?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on how much images you want and how they are aligned to each other.

The simplest form just floats the table left, see http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/8AHhG/, but this only works for the height of the table.

Another form floats the images right, see http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/8AHhG/2/, but that layout may not be disered.

You can also group the images, kind of a combination of both above, see http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/8AHhG/3/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for examples and explanation.will take it from here

Answer (score 0):

`float:right` the images and lower the width of the table

**Update**
Example

```
<div id="container">
  <table id="mytable">
  </table>
  <div id="images">
    <img />
    <img />
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#container, mytable, images {
  margin:0;
  padding:0; /* Avoid excess of width due to margins or paddings */
}
#container {
  width:1000px;
}
#mytable {
  width:600px;
  float:left;
}
#images {
  width:400px;
  float:right;
}
```

This way you should have now 2 columns, the left one which is your table, and the right one which is a div containing all the images, which should stick to the right of the table.

Comment: i have tried float right but does not work.Could you expand on what you mean by lowring the width of the table?

Comment: Setting an explicit width to the table, since I think by default they occupy all the space avaiable (width:100%). If for example you have the table and the iages inside a div, you need to set a width for the table which must be less than the width of the container div minus the width of the space occupied by the images.